# Tomcat Prevent external access to ROOT and other webapps

Tags: tomcat6

I have a Tomcat 6 server running just fine. I have external access working.
I wanted to know how to prevent someone from seeing specific webapps, for example, I dont want external access to the ROOT tomcat page. How would I go about preventing some webapps while leaving other webapps visible to external users ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

check this answer:

[How to block access to a file from being served by Tomcat?](https://serverfault.com/questions/28337/how-to-block-access-to-a-file-from-being-served-by-tomcat)

and also this link:

http://www.ka-2.ru/index.php?book=74&pg=051

(don't worry about the .ru it's in english)